# Ruby On Rails: ActionController::RoutingError No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing

I am using this [example for uploading files in Ruby on Rails.](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example)
I have some problems with routing:

Error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cars", :locale=>#<Car id: 19, car_name: "bwl",, created_at: "2013-01-27 19:12:13", updated_at: "2013-01-27 19:12:13">}):
  app/models/arraydb.rb:46:in `to_jq_car'
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :cars
match '/show', :to =>'car#index'

root :to => 'cars#index'
```

cars_controllers.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @cars = Car.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @cars.map{|car| car.to_jq_car } }
    end
  end


  def view
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @car }
    end
  end



  # GET /uploads/1/edit
  def edit
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    p_attr=params[:car]
    p_attr[:car] = params[:car][:car].first if params[:car][:car].class == Array
    @car = Car.new(p_attr)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.save
        format.html {
          render :json => [@car.to_jq_car].to_json,
          :layout => false

        }

        format.json { render json: [@car.to_jq_car].to_json, status: :created, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }      
        format.json{ render json: {name:(@arraydb.car_name).split(".").first ,error: @car.errors.messages[:car_name]}, :status =>422}

      end
    end
  end



  def destroy
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])

    @car.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cars_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end



end
```

and in car.rb I have the following function:

```
 def to_jq_car
    {
      "name" => (read_attribute(:arraydb_name)).split(".").first,
      "url" => car.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => car_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE",


    }
  end
```

rake routes:

```
cars GET        (/:locale)/cars(.:format)                                  cars#index {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
POST       (/:locale)/cars(.:format)                                  cars#create {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
new_car GET        (/:locale)/cars/new(.:format)                              cars#new {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
edit_car GET        (/:locale)/cars/:id/edit(.:format)                         cars#edit {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
car GET        (/:locale)/cars/:id(.:format)                              cars#show {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
PUT        (/:locale)/cars/:id(.:format)                              cars#update {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
DELETE     (/:locale)/cars/:id(.:format)                              cars#destroy {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
show            (/:locale)/show(.:format)                                      car#index {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
root            /(:locale)(.:format)                                           cars#index {:locale=>/en|de|es|ru|zh_cn|ar/}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't show action in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

just got same issue and managed to solve it

not sure if your case is the same as my but still..

just check if your url does not have trailing '/'

eg

`http://localhost:3000/properties/`

last '/' was useless in my case

Comment: well I have a bit more time to think. real reason is incorrect URL that is used to access [your_resource_name].json

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. Do you mean this line is incorrect  { render json: [@car.to_jq_car].to_json, status: :created, location: @car } ? The [@car.to_jq_car] is incorrect?

Comment: no. regularly json is being requested from client(browser in most cases). Issue is that you pass incorrect URL to the ajax call

https://gist.github.com/ZuBB/5064709
 
in the example url to json is incorrect. double check your **JS** code

Comment: em.. I get this error only because of this line  "delete_url" => car_path(self), it has nothing to do with JS, doesn't it?

Comment: well forget all my buzz. i have reread whole story again I have to say that all my advises were irrelevant. sorry again :(